# Modifying individual nouns in の strings

Tags: adjectives, particle-の, subordinate-clauses, modification

I haven't seen any examples that make use of this, nor have I seen any evidence to the contrary, so I thought I'd ask about it. I know that の basically connects nouns and makes them all 1 noun that can be modified as a whole, but I was also wondering if you can still modify the individual nouns within the string with subordinate clauses or adjectives.

So for example, if you wanted to say "Her beautiful eyes," how would you say it? Is this correct?

> 彼女の美しい目

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. 「彼女の美しい目」 is a grammatically correct phrase.

In fact, there is even an example sentence on Weblio with that [exact phrase](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E5%BD%BC%E5%A5%B3%E3%81%AE%E7%BE%8E%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%E7%9B%AE%22).